# Deny access to HomePlug using router Access Control

Tags: router, home-networking, powerline-networking

I want to allow a certain MAC address access the internet only during certain hours. I have a TP Link TL-WR841N router and a TP Link TL-WPA281 HomePlug. Using the Access Control panel on the router I can set the schedule I want and deny the MAC address access to the internet. However the MAC address can still access the internet through the HomePlug through wifi.

How can I setup my network so that the router Access Control settings affect the HomePlug?

Comment: You do understand that MAC address filtering is trivial to bypass right?  Honestly it sounds like the access control settings won't allow you to achieve your goals.  I suggest using a firmware that will provide you greater control.

Comment: @Ramhound The MAC address refers to a childs phone so bypassing is out of their reach (for the moment at least). I have checked the firmware on [tp-link.com](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WPA281KIT.html#Firmware) and there is no updated firmware containing Access Control similar to the router.

Comment: I was actually suggesting using firmware like `DD-WRT` or `OpenWRT`.  The simplest solution would be to only have a single access point's WiFi enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Neither of those organisations have firmware for TL-WPA281. Disabling wifi on the HomePlug is not an option.

Comment: If you cannot disable the WiFi on the Homeplug then you cannot achieve your goals.  The filtering options on the `TL-WR841N` only work if the device is connected directly to it.